# Cannot open file nor connection: "rb" errors while trying to read an excel from the computer

Tags: r, excel, readxl

```
readxl::read_excel("C:/Users/administrador/Documents", 
                   "DataImport_hatchesSDA_marc")
```

> Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In file(con, "rb") :
>     cannot open file 'C:/Users/administrador/Documents': Permission denied

Comment: It looks like your first argument `"C:/Users/administrador/Documents"` is just the directory.  It should be the path to the Excel file, including the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it has been said in the comments, I lacked the path to the particular file, so adding its name after /Documents is what made it work.